# What means Pylint when it says "Raising Exception while only classes or instances are allowed (raising-bad-type)"

Tags: python, pylint

My code is:

```
except Exception as exception:
    raise exception
```

(I used this code in a test in order to implement a finally clause to perform other tests without failing).

But Pylint says that "Raising Exception while only classes or instances are allowed (raising-bad-type)"

What does it mean? What to do?

I learnt from Pylint source code that "Used when something which is neither a class, an instance or a string is raised (i.e. a `TypeError` will be raised)". But that does not mean anything for me.

**EDITED**:

A snippet of code that raises this pylint error is:

```
# pylint: disable=invalid-name

"""A test."""

spam = True

try:
    pass
except Exception as exception:
    raise exception
finally:
    spam = False
```

I'm using python 3.6.0, pylint 1.7.0 and astroid 1.5.0 on a MacOs 10.12.3.

As Anthony Sottile pointed out, using:

```
except Exception as exception:  # sic
    raise
```

doesn't raise this pytlint warning.

All the raising-bad-type errors on my code are of this kind, so I has come to the conclusion that

```
except Exception:
    raise
```

is the proper way of raising this exception according to pylint.

However, I must say that the pylint message for this error is quite cryptic.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have a short reproducible snippet?  The one in the question alone does not trigger that lint for me.  An aside: reraising an exception is usually better done with a blank `raise` as this preserves the stacktrace

Comment: You don't need an except clause; try...finally is fine (in fact except used not to even be permitted when you have finally).

Comment: I did find an interesting micro-bug with this lint however :D https://i.fluffy.cc/KR3G8V9qqzTJrrMhZwDlMzGMwGDGxqCB.html#L13

Comment: As @AnthonySottile pointed out, using raise (instead of raise exception) is the solution. The pylint message is really misguiding (at least, for me). Thanks.

Comment: @QB_ You might like pyflakes better then: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyflakes . Its messages are much more readable and understandable.

Comment: I use regularly pyflakes and pylint. pyflakes does really warn about this issue so it is useless in this particular case. Thanks @ethanchewy

Answer (score 1):

```
        except Exception as exn:
            pass

        raise exn()
```

This seems to pass the linter.